# List categories assigned to a post

Tags: php, categories

I want to output the different categories assigned to a post. Let'say for example that a post has three categories:

- Downloads
- Games
- Video

Previously I have used `<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>` But this wraps the `<a>` in a `<span>` instead of wrapping the `<span>` in a* `<a>`...

I want to list the categories like this:

```
<a href="the_URL_of_the_category_downloads">
    <span class="the_name_of_the_category_downloads">the_name_of_the_category_downloads</span>
</a>

<a href="the_URL_of_the_category_games">
    <span class="the_name_of_the_category_downloads">the_name_of_the_category_games</span>
</a>

<a href="the_URL_of_the_category_videos">
    <span class="the_name_of_the_category_downloads">the_name_of_the_category_videos</span>
</a>
```

I am not sure how I can get this to work with php as I have very limited knowledge of PHP in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_the_category( )` instead.

**Example:**

```
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach( $categories as $category) {
    $name = $category->name;
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );

    echo "<a href='$category_link'>
            <span class=" . esc_attr( $name) . "></span>
         </a>";
}
```

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code. This gives me an error...

Comment: Hello @Arete, forgot to add a semicolon after the return statement. It's been corrected now.

Comment: Still breaks my theme structure..

Comment: @Arete Looking at your code I guess `echo` should be used instead of `return`. I changed that.

Comment: @Arete You're meant to sanitize user input and escape output, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

In the above 'answer', the last line which prints the category name is not actually doing so.

It should look like this:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach( $categories as $category) {
    $name = $category->name;
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );

    echo "<a href='$category_link'>
            <span class=" . esc_attr( $name) . ">" . esc_attr( $name) . "</span>
         </a>";
}
```